# insert new line after grep match with -z parametr (awk/sed/tr/gawk/anything)

Tags: awk, sed, grep, flags, tr

I need to use `-z` paramater with grep, which enables me to find a pattern divided to multiple lines.

```
grep -zPo myregex
```

However, it then prints

```
abc
```

instead of

```
a
b
c
```

as results

I know it is because of -z parametr, but i need to somehow insert the new lines between matches back, at results.

I tried to do so with sed, tr and awk such as

```
grep -zPo myregex | sed -e 's/$/\n/'
```

but it doesn't work, awk managed just to insert new line at the end of whole output. Someone adviced me to try it with gawk but I wasn't able to find any way to do so so far.

Comment: What is in your text file? Sample input and expected output please. What pattern are you searching for? I think you may be misunderstanding the use of the `-z` option.

Comment: for example:

a\n
b\n
c

and I need to find every occurence of "abc" pattern no matter how many whitespaces are between them. I have regex which does that with grep -z option.

Comment: Please edit your question with the actual command you're using – including the pattern you're searching for, a section of the text file that you think should match, and the output you're getting now.

Comment: the pattern is like 3 lines pearl regex to parse html and get all .pdf files from every possible valid html page, that was our taks (i know it is proven that it is not possible to parse html with regex, but our teacher obviously doesnt know). I already have all the correct matches from regex, i just need to insert new line between each match.

Comment: Everything except the exact regex is included in the question. I am getting output like: file.pdfsomefile.pdfanotherfile.pdf while it should be file.pdf\nsomefile.pdf\nanotherfile.pdf

Comment: It sounds like you have `\r`s at the end of every line. Use `cat -v` to see them and `dos2unix` or similar to remove them.

Comment: @DanM. your question is not really clear. When you state _"or example: a\n b\n c and I need to find every occurence of "abc" pattern **no matter how many whitespaces are between them.**"_ Do you mean whitespaces and/or newline characters?

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -zPo /tcp /etc/services | \
    tr '\0' '\12'
```

This example demonstrates searching for the pattern in a file, and returning only the pattern (in this case the simple "/tcp" pattern). Then due to the -z option, `grep` is separating them by nulls (\0). So `tr` the nulls to returns (\n).